# Is it compulsory that data from server should be returned in json format

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am making a call from my angularjs to post some data to the server. My question is it compulsory that the returned response from server must be in JSON format???

`resource.save($scope.customer,
               function(data){
               alert(data); })`

as in the above code, data is the response from server

Answer (score 2):

It expects JSON by default check out the documentation about transform on this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L12

Comment: is there any way to change the default behavior??

Comment: yup you should be able to just setup your own transformResponse to deal with the data and override the http defaults or provide that as the options if it's just a one off case